# How to build a plot that evaluates the Xth percentile in R

Tags: r

I have a single column data frame of race times called `RaceTimes`, with the data frame called `R5`.
I don't know what ggplot to use and how to get the percentile on the x-axis.

Comment: Need a data example and an explanation of  what "how to get the percentile on the x-axis." means. Are you trying for a histogram?

Comment: A histogram would work.